# Rotate a vector in 4D space

Tags: matrices, geometry, euclidean-geometry, analytic-geometry, rotations

Given 2 vectors $m$, $n$ and point $p$ which define a rotation plane $P$ in 4-dimensional space $R^4$, how can I rotate any vector/point $v$ by angle $a$?

This question is a continuation of [another question at gamedev](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/128656/camera-rotation-in-4d), where I asked how I could rotate a camera in 4D space.
I've later found out that the answer was not sufficient, because it rotates the 3 orthonormal vectors (the fourth can be calculated) defining the direction of the camera in planes defined by vectors of the canonical basis. What I would like to achieve, is to rotate the camera in the rotation plane defined by 2 of the 4 vectors defining the direction of the camera and its location.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suggestion:  Move your origin to $p$, orthonormalize $m,n$ to get $e_1$,$e_2$ and supplement with two orthonormal vectors $e_3,e_4$. Let $E=[e_1\  e_2\  e_3 \ e_4]$ denote the (4 by 4) matrix of these column vectors.

A vector in these coordinates is described by $v=Ex$ with  $x\in {\Bbb R}^4$.

A rotation in the plane spanned by $e_1,e_2$ is given by $f_a(Ex)=E M_a x=E M_a E^{-1} v= E M_a E^T v$ with
$$  M_a=\left( \begin{matrix}
 \cos a & -\sin a & 0 & 0\\
 \sin a & \cos a & 0 & 0\\
 0 & 0 & 1 & 0\\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 1
\end{matrix}
\right)$$

Comment: Could you please elaborate on what "orthogonal complement" and "matrix of these column vectors" mean in this case?

Comment: I have removed the first remark. It was just the question if you want to leave invariant the vectors orthogonal to the plane? (I suspect so). $e_3$ and $e_4$ may be obtained by Gram-Schmitt.

Comment: So first, the $E^T$ transforms the rotation plane to be parallel to the $xy$ plane, then $M_a$ is applied, which rotates the vector by the angle, and finally, the vector is transformed back using $E$. Am I understanding it correctly?

Comment: Yes, that is indeed a correct interpretation. You may also simply see what happens to each of the vectors $e_1,e_2,e_3,e_4$. The two last stay invariant and the two first get rotated among themselves.

Comment: Thank you for the help, much appreciated!